# Issue when hiding the SharePoint 2013 calendar event tooltip

Tags: jquery, events, sharepoint, calendar

I am trying to hide/remove event tooltip (it displays when we mouse-over on any event in calendar view).
For that I use below css class.

```
    .ms-acal-default-hover 
{
    display:none;
}
```

It hide the tooltip but it creates flickering when we mouse over on the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, you could use jquery to remove the title of the class `ms-acal-item`. The below code would help you achieve this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
     setInterval(function(){
        $('.ms-acal-item').attr('title','')
        },500);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Michael. It is what I wanted.